# Fragment in TabLayout: Google map not updated

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have TabLayout into a Fragment. Every tab contains another fragment. One of this fragment contains a map. The first time I select the map tab, map is loaded but it's not updated with my long and lat values. From the second time map is loaded and updated correctly.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class GpsTab extends MapFragment implements
        OnMapReadyCallback {
    private boolean needsInit = false;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            needsInit = true;
        }

        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
        if (needsInit) {
            CameraUpdate center =
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(72.9655446,
                            -47.3458168));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);
        }

        addMarker(map, 72.9655446, -47.3458168, R.string.marker_name ,R.string.marker_address);

    }

    private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon,
                           int title, int snippet) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .title(getString(title))
                .snippet(getString(snippet)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed whether your onMapReady callback is being called the first time you select the map tab or does none of that code execute until the second time?

Comment: is no updates mean no marker in your map fragment?

Comment: @ntaloventi no updates means that the map is loaded correctly, the marker is added, but the map is centered on Africa, without any move to my base location

Comment: @shiv I have tree tab: gps is the third. The first time I call the fragment containing the tab layout, the selected tab is the first: if I select second or thrid tab onMapReady is called. If I move from first to third onMapReady is called. If I move from first to second onMapReady is called. If I move from second to third onMapRead isn't called.

Comment: The reason onMapReady is not being called when you move from second to third fragment but called in other instances is because your ViewPager for the TabLayout by default loads fragments on either side of the currently showing fragment. See docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). Considering your answer to @ntaloventi stating that the marker is added but the view isn't updated, I have a feeling your `needsInit` variable is false at the time `onMapReady` is called causing the camera update code to be skipped